# How can get specified selector with jquery in my case?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to show all content below `a` tag such as `article11`  and `article12` mouse entered `▼` in `content1`.

```js
$(function() {
  $("ul#nav span").hover(function() {
    console.log("i am in mouseover");
    $(this).parent().silbings().next().show();
  }, function() {
    console.log("i am in mouse left");
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul#nav li {
  width: 120px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

ul#nav>li>ul>li>a {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="nav">
  <li>
    <a href=""><span>▼</span>content1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">article11</a></li>
      <li><a href="">article12</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href=""><span>▼</span>content2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">article21</a></li>
      <li><a href="">article22</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

When `this` denotes $("ul#nav span"),my try to point to expected tag :

```
$(this).parent().silbings().next()  
$(this).parent()[0].silbings()[0].next()[0]
```

Both of them is wrong.How can get specified selector with jquery in my case?
To correct my typo,why `$(this).parent().siblings().children()` can't get expected element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you have a typo. The correct method name is `siblings()` not `silbings()`. You don't need that call anyway, as `next()` works on sibling elements.

Secondly, your logic doesn't work as you're calling `show()` on the sibling `ul` element when that is already displayed. Your CSS is hiding the child `a` elements instead, so you need to `find()` them. Also note that you can just call `toggle()` instead of providing two handlers to `hover()`:

```js
$(function() {
  $("ul#nav span").hover(function() {
    $(this).parent().next().find('a').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul#nav li {
  width: 120px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

ul#nav > li > ul > li > a {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="nav">
  <li>
    <a href=""><span>▼</span>content1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">article11</a></li>
      <li><a href="">article12</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href=""><span>▼</span>content2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">article21</a></li>
      <li><a href="">article22</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

However, with all that said, it makes *far* more sense to do this in CSS alone. If you use the `:hover` pseudo selector on the `a` element you expand the hit area for triggering the menu to appear:

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul#nav li {
  width: 120px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

ul#nav > li > ul {
  display: none;
}
ul#nav > li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}

a {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="nav">
  <li>
    <a href=""><span>▼</span>content1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">article11</a></li>
      <li><a href="">article12</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href=""><span>▼</span>content2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">article21</a></li>
      <li><a href="">article22</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why $(this).parent().siblings().children() can't get expected element?

Comment: Because that looks at the `li` elements which again, are already visible. It's the `a` elements that are hidden.

Comment: $(this).parent().siblings().children().children() get my desired element.

Comment: Sure it'll work, but damn that's ugly. Just use `find()` like the answer shows, or better yet use CSS.